# Why can't I add an event listener to each of my elements in my array, not just the last one when using knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I understand how to add an event listener to all of my elements in my array in vanilla js. But when i use knockout js only the last element in my array is affected.
I made a function in js file

```
//when any of the li elements in the ul are clicked run this function
this.zoomOnLocation = function(){
  //zooms in on the location you clicked
  map.setZoom(18);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```

Then I have my ul and li tags that triggers the function when clicked

```
<ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: locations">
    <li data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.zoomOnLocation"></li>
</ul>
```

But whenever I click on that li i always get the last location in my locations array. Why is this happening? If you would like to view my project just click [here](https://enightengale.github.io/neighborhood_map/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass each individual location to the zoomOnLocation. Like this:

```
//when any of the elements in ul are clicked run this function
this.zoomOnLocation = function(data) {
  //zooms in on the location you clicked
  map.setZoom(18);
  map.setCenter(data.location);
}
```

The reason you're getting the last location is because you define one marker (`var marker`) and continually re-set it while you're going through the for loop.